# nginx with php-fpm in https returns blank page in php

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've successfully  setuped nginx with php-fpm (with http and https),
but when i run a php file in `https` connection i goa q blank page.

However running php file in `http` works fine,i am using the same `php-fpm` configuration for `http` and `https`

**nginx-configuration for php-fpm(http and https)**

```
location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
           }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           index index.php index.html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

**SSL configuration**

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /var/www/html/cushbu.com/public;
   }
```

**Note**.

Running `.html` file in `https` returns ouput

eg:

`https://<ip>/test.html`  //returns output

`https://<ip>/test.php`  //returns blank output.

`http://<ip>/test.php`  //returns output

Comment: You should add location block inside ssl server block also to serve .php files.

Comment: Actually thats included in server block